# Is mysqlcheck -q just as thorough as mysqlcheck -r

Tags: mysql, database, repair

Afternoon,
I'm currently wondering if mysqlcheck -q which stands for quick. Just as thorough as mysqlcheck -r. This isn't in the idea of repairing the tables within a MySQL database, but to see if the discovery of any errors show themselves just as thoroughly. The idea is to bypass the length of time to which the entire repair takes. It's much easier to do a quick check, and does quick possibly shift any table information?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysqlcheck -q doesn't scan through rows. It only goes through indexes. If there are any incorrect links in rows it doesn't check them. I would avoid using -q unless you know there are no incorrect links in rows.

mysqlcheck -r simply repairs the tables. Please check mysqlcheck utility man page for more details.

Comment: I guess this would come down to my next question. I've been looking through quite a few commands, but what would be the best way to looking through all rows. and tables. Without affecting the table itself, but just to throw up an error for increase of speed?